# How to fix segmentation error 11 in c++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, binary-tree

I am currently writing a binary tree project in c++ and it is giving me some errors that I am struggling to understand. The error in question is a segmentation error that I have no idea how to fix. Below is the code from one one the files where all the functions are written. The function in particular that is giving me an issue is the last one - the print_pre_order_private function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

#include "BT.h"

using namespace std;

BT::BT()
{
    root = NULL;  //makes sure pointer isn't pointing at anything
}

BT::node* BT::create_leaf(int key)
{
    node* n = new node;
    n->key = key;
    n->left = NULL;
    n->right = NULL;

    return n;
}

void BT::add_leaf(int key)
{
    add_leaf_private(key, root);
} 

void BT::add_leaf_private(int key, node* Ptr)
{
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        root = create_leaf(key);
    }

    else if(key < Ptr->key)
    {
        if(Ptr->left != NULL)
        {
             add_leaf_private(key, Ptr->left);
        }
        else
        {
            Ptr->left = create_leaf(key);
        }
    }

    else if(key > Ptr->key)
    {
        if(Ptr->right != NULL)
        {
             add_leaf_private(key, Ptr->right);
        }
        else
        {
            Ptr->right = create_leaf(key);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The key " << key << " has already been added to the    tree\n";
    }
}

void BT::print_in_order()
{
    print_in_order_private(root);
}

void BT::print_in_order_private(node* Ptr)
{
    if(root != NULL)
    {
        if(Ptr->left != NULL)
        {
            print_in_order_private(Ptr->left);
        } 
        cout << Ptr->key << " ";
        if(Ptr->right != NULL)
        {
            print_in_order_private(Ptr->right);
        }
    } 
    else
    {
        cout << "The tree is empty\n";
    }
}

BT::node* BT::return_node(int key)
{
    return return_node_private(key, root);
}

BT::node* BT::return_node_private(int key, node* Ptr)
{
    if(Ptr != NULL)
    {
        if(Ptr->key == key)
        {
            return Ptr;
        }

        else
        {
            if(key < Ptr->key)
            {
                return return_node_private(key, Ptr->left);
            }

            else
            {
                return return_node_private(key, Ptr->right);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}

int BT::return_root_key()
{
    if(root != NULL)
    {
        return root->key;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}

void BT::print_children(int key)
{
   node* Ptr = return_node(key);

    if(Ptr != NULL)
    {
        cout << "Parent Node = " << Ptr->key << endl;

        Ptr->left == NULL ?
        cout << "Left child = NULL\n":
        cout << "Left child = " << Ptr->left->key << endl;

        Ptr->right == NULL ?
        cout << "Right child = NULL\n":
        cout << "Right child = " << Ptr->right->key << endl;
     }
     else
     {
        cout << "Key " << key << " is not in the tree\n";
     }

 }

int BT::find_smallest()
{
    return find_smallest_private(root);
}

int BT::find_smallest_private(node* Ptr)
{
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        cout << "The tree is empty\n";
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        if(Ptr->left != NULL)
        {
            return find_smallest_private(Ptr->left);
        }
        else
        {
            return Ptr->key;
        }
    }
}


void BT::remove_node(int key)
{
     remove_node_private(key, root);
}  

void BT::remove_node_private(int key, node* parent)
{
    if(root != NULL)
   {
    if(root->key == key)
    {
        remove_root_match();
    }
    else
    {
        if(key < parent->key && parent->left != NULL)
        {
             parent->left->key == key ?
             remove_match(parent, parent->left, true) :
             remove_node_private(key, parent->left);
        }   
        else if(key < parent->key && parent->right != NULL)
        {
             parent->right->key == key ?
             remove_match(parent, parent->right, true) :
             remove_node_private(key, parent->right);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "The key " << key << " was not found in the tree\n";
        }
    }
}
else
{
    cout << "The tree is empty\n";
}
}

void BT::remove_root_match()
{
    if(root != NULL)
    {
        node* delPtr = root;
        int root_key = root->key;
        int smallest_right_subtree;

        //case 0 - 0 children
        if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)
        {
            root = NULL;
            delete delPtr;
        }

        //case 1 - 1 child
        else if(root->left == NULL && root->right != NULL)
        {
            root = root->right;
            delPtr->right = NULL;
            delete delPtr;
            cout << "The root node with key " << root_key << " was deleted. " 
            << " The new root contains key " << root->key << endl;

        }
        else if(root->right == NULL && root->left != NULL)
        {
            root = root->left;
            delPtr->left = NULL;
            delete delPtr;
            cout << "The root node with key " << root_key << " was deleted. " 
            << " The new root contains key " << root->key << endl;

        }
        //case 2 - 2 children
        else
        {
            smallest_right_subtree = find_smallest_private(root->right);
            remove_node_private(smallest_right_subtree, root);
            root->key = smallest_right_subtree;
            cout << "The rout key containing key " << root_key
            << " was overwritten with key " << root->key << endl;
        }
   }
    else
    {
        cout << "Cannot remove root. Tree is empty\n";
    }
}

void BT::remove_match(node* parent, node* match, bool left)
{
    if(root != NULL)
    {
        node* delPtr;
        int match_key = match->key;
        int smallest_right_subtree;

        //case 0 - 0 children
        if(match->left == NULL && match->right == NULL)
        {
            delPtr = match;
            left == true ? parent->left = NULL : parent->right = NULL;
            delete delPtr;
            cout << "The node containing key " << match_key << " was removed\n";
        }

        //case 1 - 1 child
        else if(match->left == NULL && match->right != NULL)
        {
            left == true ? parent->left = match->left : parent->right = match->right;
            match->left = NULL;
            delPtr = match;
            delete delPtr;
            cout << "The node containing key " << match_key << " was removed\n";
        }
        //case 2 - 2 children
        else
        {
            smallest_right_subtree = find_smallest_private(match->right);
            remove_node_private(smallest_right_subtree, match);
            match->key = smallest_right_subtree;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "Cannot remove match. The tree is empty";
    }
}

void print_pre_order()
{
    print_pre_order_private(root);
}
void print_pre_order_private(node* Ptr)
{
    if(root != NULL)
    {
        cout << Ptr->key << " ";
        print_pre_order_private(Ptr->left);
        print_pre_order_private(Ptr->right);
    }
}
```

Any help in fixing this situation is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: And *where* do the crash happen? You have tried running your program in a debugger to locate the crash?

Comment: By the way, do *do* obey [the rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29)?

Comment: In print_pre_order_private(node* Ptr) function. Shouldn't this be  "if(Ptr != NULL)" instead of "if(root != NULL)" ?. I think there is the crash

Comment: This is not a good question for StackOverflow. See http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

In print_pre_order_private(node* Ptr) function. Shouldn't this be "if(Ptr != NULL)" instead of "if(root != NULL)" ?. I think there is the crash.

Since you have designed "print_pre_order_private()" function as a recursive function you should check for the validity of "Ptr" instead of always checking for the validity of "root", since the left/right/both of the child may be NULL at the very bottom of the tree depending on your input.

Comment: ah thank you so much. I changed if(root !=null) to if(Ptr != null) and it worked. thanks again. :)

Comment: you are welcome!. Also please see the other answer by @Trinimon to make sure everything works right!

Comment: whilst I have your attention :P another problem is that me printing in pre and post order aren't working properly. any ideas why that might be happening?